# Magento 2 Extension attribute to Payment method

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

I want to set Extension attribute to

```
V1/carts/mine/shipping-information
```

API response like below.

```
{
    "payment_methods": [
        {
            "code": "braintree_cc_vault",
            "title": "Stored Cards",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "test-data" : 1
            }

        },
        {
            "code": "braintree_paypal",
            "title": "PayPal",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "test-data" : 1
            }
        },
```

Anyone have idea how can i add ?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can't just use extension attributes, since the core code was removed in this commit:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/012172b74fcb4410d4d0c6be4fe593241b57d004#diff-399fed320da1993bdfbe19518d6b5b0b

Try override file `vendor/magento/module-quote/Api/Data/PaymentMethodInterface.php` and restore that removed part from the commit. Then set your extension attributes.

Comment: anybody has any idea why the interface was removed? it's not clean to me from commit message...

Comment: anyway, this solution is definitely not effortless, as in addition to having to patch `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentMethodInterface`, one also has to patch `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod`, and that's not enough, since the latter is deprecated in favor of `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter`, which contrarily to AbstractMethod does **not** extend `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractExtensibleModel`...